# Error getting response, check your network connection issue with cf ic login command

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, containers, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Have an Ubuntu image with Docker 1.12.6 installed.
Login via `cf login` and it's fine.
Try to `cf ic login` and get the following:

```
Generating client certificates for IBM Containers...
FAILED

Error getting response, check your network connection

API endpoint is:  https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.54.0)
```

Try to do a `cf ic init` and get the same response.  The Ubuntu image is running in an ESX environment.  I have confirmed the issue is not with my account as I connect successfully from a Windows machine with no problems.

The Ubuntu image running is ESX is not using a proxy.  Have set environment variables (three for DOCKER_HOST etc) and it still fails.  However, when I do set the variables, I can no longer run any Docker commands.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try running your command with the verbose option set: `cf ic --verbose init`. The extra output might help you figure out what's going wrong.

If it doesn't help, open a support ticket and include the verbose output from your command and the output of `cf ic info`.